# Titan mountains = downwelling in it's ocean?

Tags: planetary-science, water, titan

Titan, [unlike earth](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/4892/can-a-cosmic-impact-break-earths-crust-in-large-area-exposing-the-magma-ocean/4895#4895) has a liquid (mostly) water ocean beneath it's icy crust. (I think) this prevents plate tectonics because it isn't viscous enough to drag the crust with it. The heating of said ocean isn't uniform, setting up convection currents. Downwelling water will be cooler than the upwelling water at the same depth. Cooler water means a thicker crust, which means the top of the (less dense) crust must be higher for the same total weight, much like how [mountain roots](https://www.geological-digressions.com/tag/mountain-roots/) on Earth keep mountains from sinking.

Is this a plausible mechanism for the formation of some of the mountain ranges on Titan?

Comment: You must be a geophysicist. Good for you!

Comment: Titan is less unlike Earth than you think.  It may not be liquid, but we have [evidence for water deep in the mantle of Earth](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/359/6380/1136).

Comment: How do we know that "The heating of said ocean isn't uniform, setting up convection currents"? It's hard to imagine anything natural could be completely uniform, but is there some evidence of these convection currents?

Comment: I think you're right that the water of the ocean is just not viscous enough to drag the at least 50 km thick ice crust with it.

Comment: "Kevin Kostlan" - do you see plate tectonics as the only way for mountain formation? What about vulcanism, gravitational squeezing from Saturn, asteroid collisions?

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance: No, I was just proposing a mechanism that doesn't seem to be discussed much.

Comment: @KevinKostlan - It is an interesting concept: " mountain roots on Earth keep mountains from sinking" - but I never heard of it. Could you share a reference?

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance: I fixed the second link. Generally the mantle is Peridotite (density ~3.3g/cm^3) and the crust is mostly stuff like silica, basalt, granite, limestone, etc with densities around 2.7-3.0. All materials can compress a bit with extreme pressure, but the ~10% difference in density *at any given pressure* remains. Since the mantle is like glacier ice (i.e. *solid* but can flow) you have a crust "floating" on it. The total weight of a vertical column of rock+water, for 100km+ size geographic regions, is similar whether it be an abyssal plain or the Tibetan plateau.

Comment: As another line of thought, what is known about tidal forces on Titan, or other external gravitational forces & their ability to induce non-uniform stresses in Titan's crust that could that result in mountain formation?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not knowledgable enough to speak to plausibility of the downwelling mechanism, but it doesn't seem to be included in the literature reviewed by [Lalich et al in Diverse evolution of mountains and hummocks on Titan as observed by the Cassini RADAR altimeter](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0019103521004255).  I can't review the whole paper, but from what I can see (emphasis mine):

> Hypotheses for the construction and evolution of mountains and hummocks and have been difficult to test given unknowns surrounding Titan's tectonics, surface materials, and the detailed topography of the mountains themselves. While SARTopo and radar clinometry measurements are helpful for estimating elevation over long length scales (hundreds of meters to 10 km) they do not provide any information about smaller scale topography, which would contribute to better constraints on the processes involved in mountain and hummock evolution. Some observations and modeling studies have suggested that **mountain building through lithospheric shortening** may be common on Titan (Mitri et al., 2010; Cook-Hallett et al., 2015; Liu et al., 2016). Others have pointed to sub-parallel chains of mountains observed in SAR images, suggesting that construction is driven by **extensional tectonic processes** similar to those responsible for the basin and range topography of the western United States (Radebaugh et al., 2007; Lopes et al., 2010; Matteoni et al., 2020), an idea that is also supported by some models (Cook-Hallett et al., 2015). A third possibility is that mountains and hummocks on Titan are actually **erosional remnants of a previously deposited layer of icy materials** (Radebaugh et al., 2007; Birch et al., 2017). Multiple features of this type could exist within a single radar footprint and could manifest either as part of larger terrain units or as more isolated deposits, consistent with observations of both large-scale mountainous regions and more solitary hummocks. Without higher resolution measurements, it is difficult to distinguish between these different formation scenarios.
>
> To better measure mountain and hummock topography, especially over short length scales, we applied delay-doppler processing to Cassini RADAR altimetry observations (Poggiali et al., 2019) and compared the resulting waveforms to simulations. The combination of advanced data processing and simulation techniques allows us to draw inferences regarding sub-footprint scale topography, even if direct measurements are still not possible. Through careful examination and simulation of their altimetric waveforms, we found that many mountains on Titan are heavily eroded, with elevation varying between mountain peaks and plains-level terrain within a single radar footprint.

I'm sure this is very incomplete as an answer, but maybe it has pointers to a place to start.